# Cannot send messages from Microsoft Bot Framework

Tags: windows, frameworks, emulation, bots

Version 3.5.20

The emulator at first is supposed to return a response with the number of characters of a user input string. However even after using the default endpoint url which is http://localhost:3978/api/messages, whenever inputting a string, the message is not sent. What appears in the log is show in one of the images below.

When accessing the app settings, the emulator port is modifiable. The emulator port was 9002 by default and even changing it to 9000 (which I remember seeing in some other posts) did not fix the issue.

**Log**

```
Emulator listening on http://[::]:9002
failed to start ngrok: spawn D:\Downloads\Setup\ngrok-stable-windows-amd64\ngrok.
Click here to configure ngrok.
Checking for new verson...
Application is up to date.
```

Answer (score 0):

From the contents of your log, it would seem that no attempt was made to connect to a bot. When you enter your bot's endpoint `http://localhost:3978/api/messages`, a panel should appear with a CONNECT button. Did you click on this button?

[image: Screenshot of the UI]

Answer (score 0):

Ok I just figured it out.

After you create the 'Bot Application' project in Visual Studio, you need to run the project and then the browser will display a message. The url of this webpage would be localhost:3979 by default. This four digit number must also be in the endpoint URL of the 'Bot Framework Emulator'.

Just click on the 'Enter your endpoint URL' field on top and you will be able to edit it. Mine was set to '3978' by default and after changing it to '3979' the issue was solved.

Comment: The default should be 3978.